# Looking for high resolution land use (not land cover) data sets for world?

Tags: data, land-use

I am looking for high resolution land use data sets for the world.

This question is NOT to be confused with an earlier question - [Equivalent of CORINE land cover data sets for rest of world](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123200/equivalent-of-corine-land-cover-data-sets-for-rest-of-world) which refers to land cover.

My question relates to high resolution land use data sets.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_use

Comment: Could you describe a bit more precisely what "high" resolution you are looking for? Spatial and/or semantic resolution?

Comment: @Julien - definitely spatial.

Comment: there is no high spatial resolution global LU map from what I know, but you could find useful links http://freegisdata.rtwilson.com/index.html#land-use for country by country maps.

Comment: @radouxju - what about the MODIS land use data ?

Comment: MODIS (MCD12Q1) is land cover oriented, and with a spatial resolution of 500 m.

Comment: @radouxju - can temporal landuse information derived from landsat satellite data ?

Comment: Usually, land use cannot be derived from remote sensing without the use of ancillary data. For instance, even if you detect a building (land cover), it will be most of the time impossible to tell if it is part of a residential, an industrial or a commercial area(land use). However, in some places of the world, the size and color of the roofs can help (otherwise, you need socio-economic information). Maybe you should edit your question with the land use type that you need. Some land uses indeed have a one to one relationship with land cover, and those can then be mapped using remote sensing.

Comment: @radouxju- do not have an issue rewriting the question. But I have only meteorological/climatological use cases. Do I really need to differentiate between residential and industrial and commercial areas ? On the other hand if I were in disaster management then the mapping would be more relevant. Comments ?