# Latitude and longitude information of agricultural land

Tags: land-survey, agriculture

Is there a method by which I can get latlong details of agricultural land?

Latlong information of 1 point in the land is not useful, as I want details of the entire agriculture boundary (from latlong info, I should be able to tell the shape of the land).

Comment: You need to add more info. Like what data you have access to, which GIS software you are working with etc.

Comment: I think OP wants to know how to get the data. In Europe we have Corine Land Cover data, not sure about other places. Here some questions on remote sensing: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-sensing?sort=votes&pageSize=30

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123200/equivalent-of-corine-land-cover-data-sets-for-rest-of-world

Comment: Land is usually show as polygons, and you can get the Lat/Lngs from the vertices, but some polygons may follow an irregular boundary with many vertices, or cross roads where two polygons make up one property. So it's not really easy to model as points. Not to mention projections can change the shape.

Answer (score 1):

as @Bera mentioned, more details are required to understand this question.

According to this open ended question, the answer is "Yes". You can get lat long by digitizing it from google earth/or google maps in QGIS. In addition, you can also do Android based survey of fields to collect lat long info.